# How to filter rows (numeric) in R with regular expressions using data.table

Tags: r, regex, data.table

I have a data.table that looks like this:

```
ID         Name
9123000000 Alf
9123400000 Olive
8123000000 Gary 

dt[grep("000000$", ID)]
```

I tried to filter the rows that contains the next regular expression "000000$" but it does not return any results. I checked in a regular match application and it's correct. ¿What am I doing wrong?
The results I would expect is only having the rows with name Alf and Gary.

Comment: If the numbers are really big, it may not match

Comment: Perhaps try this: type `options(scipen = 100)` and then try `dt[grep("000000$", ID)]` again. Those numbers are possibly stored as `9.123e+09` which, converted into a string, doesn't match your pattern anymore.

Comment: you could also do `dt[grep("0{6}$", formatC(ID, format = 'f', drop0trailing = TRUE))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are numbers, the conversion to character for `grepl` is likely seeing scientific notation:

```r
as.character(dt$ID)
# [1] "9.123e+09"  "9123400000" "8.123e+09"
```

We can get around that by using `sprintf`:

```r
sprintf("%0.0f", dt$ID)
# [1] "9123000000" "9123400000" "8123000000"
```

(I'm assuming that you do not have or do not care about decimals.)

Therefore, the filter should be feasible with

```r
dt[grepl("000000$", sprintf("%0.0f", ID)),]
#           ID   Name
#        <num> <char>
# 1: 9.123e+09    Alf
# 2: 8.123e+09   Gary
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

These are big numbers.  We may need special package

```
library(gmp)
grep("000000$", as.bigz(v1))
[1] 1
grep("000000$", v1)
integer(0)
```

Thus, in the OP's example, it should be

```
dt[grep("000000$", as.bigz(ID))]
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(9123000000, 9123400000)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you install the `bit64` package, then `fread()` can import columns with huge numbers as the `integer64` type which is a default in the `bit64` package.